# Accessing the value of a control on other form in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Listbox object that is located in a subform in a tabbed form in access. I wish to access the selected value in it when I open another form in a new window using the below:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "New form", , , , , acDialog
```

Assuming my main form with the tabbed interface is called "Main Page" ,the subform is called "Search by project" and the listbox object is called "filteredList", I wish to get the value from filteredList in "New form" during loading of the form. I am confused by the various syntax provided online as they do not seem to be working for me. May I know what is the correct syntax? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing this. Let us say that your code to open the second form is on Main Page and you have a simple, not multi-select listbox, you can use an OpenArg:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "New form", , , , , acDialog, _
    Me.[NameOfSubformControlNotFormContained].Form.filteredList
```

If the code is in the subform, you say:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "New form", , , , , acDialog, Me.filteredList
```

To refer to a subform from another form:

```
Forms![Main Form]![NameOfSubformControlNotFormContained].Form!filteredList
```

Or

```
Forms![Main Form].[NameOfSubformControlNotFormContained].Form.filteredList
```

See also: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Hmm I have tried Forms![Main Form]![NameOfSubformControlNotFormContained].Form!filteredList.value and added it to as a watch but it tells me that <Object doesn't support this property or method>...

Comment: That error suggests that you either have the wrong object or your form has become corrupt. To check the object, see http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Referring_to_a_control_on_a_subform. For corruption, try compact & repair and decompile, and if that fails, import into a new database (Allen Browne http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html)