# Pass values between forms in access 2010 vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox in an  access 2010 form , named cd_numero I need to pass the value to another form I have try this way:

```
     DoCmd.OpenForm "com_PedsOrdMon", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
     Forms!com_pedsordmon!cd.value = me.cd.value

    Me.Requery
```

the destination form is com_PedsOrdMon and the control is label3, what is wrong in the line form.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  Have you stepped through your code to see what the form thinks the value is?  It may just be a refresh issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the value of a control on other form in access 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197687/accessing-the-value-of-a-control-on-other-form-in-access-2010)

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way we do it.

```
stFrmName = "Com_pedordmon"
stLinkCriteria = me.cd.value

DoCmd.OpenForm stFrmName, , , stLinkCriteria
```

Then in the Com_pedordmon OnLoad/OnOpen event grab the criteria and set your control property.